# Capturing all operators, parentheses and numbers separately in "(3 + 44)* 5 / 7" with Regex

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

For input string: `st = "(3 + 44)* 5 / 7"`

I'm looking to get the following result using only regex: `["(", "3", "+", "44", ")", "*", "5", "/", "7"]`

Attempts:

1. ```
   >>> re.findall("[()\d+\-*/].?", st)
   ['(3', '+ ', '44', ')*', '5 ', '/ ', '7']
   ```

   But I need to capture the parentheses in `'(3'` and `')*'` separately as well.
2. ```
   >>> re.findall("[()\d+\-*/]?", st)    
   ['(', '3', '', '+', '', '4', '4', ')', '*', '', '5', '', '/', '', '7', '']
   ```

   This gives tons of blank tokens.

Comment: How about `re.findall("(\d+|\S)", st)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use multi-character constructs like `\d+` in a character class.

So you can do it by brute force like this:

```
re.findall(r"\(|\)|\d+|-|\*|/", st)
```

Or you can use a character class for single-character tokens, alternated with other things:

```
re.findall(r"[()\-*/]|\d+", st)
```

Comment: This would ignore and just skip all bullshit in the input (`3 + bullshit 4` would turn out as `[ "3", "+", "4" ]`).  Probably not intended.

Comment: Aha, I thought the character set construct was the only way to do an OR in regex. The `|` symbol is what I was looking for.